# Как считать дату для заданного месяца?

Tags: c#, xml

Всем привет, скажите, у меня есть XML файл такого содержания

```
<Пользователь>Дмитрий</Пользователь>
<Пол>Мужчина</Пол>
<Дата>
    <Год>1997</Год>
    <Месяц>6</Месяц>
    <День>20</День>
    <Деятельность>Книги</Деятельность>
</Дата>

<Пользователь>Анна</Пользователь>
<Пол>Женщина</Пол>
<Дата>
    <Год>1993</Год>
    <Месяц>6</Месяц>
    <День>20</День>
    <Деятельность>Путешествия</Деятельность>
</Дата>
```

Мне нужно считать месяц и день, и загнать их в переменную, но не просто любую дату, а только, к примеру, где месяц int month = прочитать дату;

```
if(DateTime.Now.Month == month)
{
    MessageBox("УРА ВСЁ РАБОТАЕТ");
}
```

Я попробовал так:

```
int day = 0;
int month = 0;

XmlTextReader read = new XmlTextReader("user.xml");

while (read.Read())// но при  компиляции тут ошибка
{
    if (read.Name == "<Дата>" && read.GetAttribute("<День>") == "7")
    {
        if (month == DateTime.Now.Month && DateTime.Now.Day + 7 == day)
            Mess.ShowBalloonTip(2000, "Есть новое событие", "Сегодня есть событие", ToolTipIcon.Info);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("СЕГОДНЯ НЕТУ CОБЫТИЙ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых: имя узла функции получают уже без угловых скобок, т.е. писать надо вот так:

```
read.Name == "Дата"
```

Во-вторых: логичнее структуру файла было бы сделать так:

```
<Пользователи>
    <Пользователь Name="Дмитрий">
       <Пол>Мужчина</Пол>
       <Дата>
          <Год>1997</Год>
          <Месяц>6</Месяц>
          <День>20</День>
          <Деятельность>Книги</Деятельность>
       </Дата>
   </Пользователь>
...
</Пользователи>
```

В-третьих: ошибка у вас появилась скорее всего потому, что у вас неправильно задан, или вообще не задан, узел декларации. Он должен иеть следующий вид:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Ну и еще я бы использовал в качестве имен узлов все-таки англоязычные слова, чтобы избежать проблем с кодировкой.

Comment: А где этот узел надо прописать?

Comment: В самом начале файле, перед всеми данными

Comment: Если говорить о логической структуре данных в файле, то узел `<Деятельность>`, по-моему нужно вынести из узла `<Дата>`.

Comment: Вообще да. Я как-то не обратил внимания

Answer (score 2):

Надо немного модифицировать этот ответ.
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Test {
    public static void Main() {
    string month = "5";
        XElement source = XElement.Load(@"source.xml");

```
    var parsed = (from date in source.Descendants("Дата")
                  where date.Element("Месяц").Value == month
                  let d = new {
                      Day = date.Element("День").Value,
                      Month = date.Element("Месяц").Value,
                      Year = date.Element("Год").Value
                  } select d)
                  .ToArray();

    foreach(var d in parsed) {
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Спасибо, но ошибка осталась та же

     There are multiple root elements. Line 2, position 2

Как "обернуть" всё в <xml></xml>?

Comment: Так надо просто добавить корневой элемент.

    <?xml ...?>
    <Документ>
        ...
    </Документ>